# gtsummary: Controlling digits for a continuous2 variable

Tags: r, gtsummary

In `gtsummary`, continuous variables have only one line of statistics associated with them, and the number of decimal places for each output number is controlled by offering a numeric vector that has as many integers as there are numbers to style:

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl_summary(iris, 
            by = Species,
            digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(3, 2, 1))) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

#>   **Characteristic** **setosa**, N = 50 **versicolor**, N = 50
#> 1       Sepal.Length  5.000 (4.80, 5.2)      5.900 (5.60, 6.3)
#> 2        Sepal.Width  3.400 (3.20, 3.7)      2.800 (2.53, 3.0)
#> 3       Petal.Length  1.500 (1.40, 1.6)      4.350 (4.00, 4.6)
#> 4        Petal.Width  0.200 (0.20, 0.3)      1.300 (1.20, 1.5)
```

But for `type = continuous2` variables, `gtsummary` generates several lines of statistics for a single variable. How do you control decimal places for these?

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl_summary(iris, 
            by = Species,
            type = list(Sepal.Length ~ "continuous2"),
            statistic = list(all_continuous2() ~ c("{median} ({p25} - {p75})", 
                                                   "{min} - {max}",
                                                   "{mean} ({sd})")),
            include = c(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)
            ) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

#>   **Characteristic** **setosa**, N = 50 **versicolor**, N = 50
#> 1       Sepal.Length               <NA>                   <NA>
#> 2       Median (IQR) 5.00 (4.80 - 5.20)     5.90 (5.60 - 6.30)
#> 3              Range        4.30 - 5.80            4.90 - 7.00
#> 4          Mean (SD)        5.01 (0.35)            5.94 (0.52)
#> 5        Sepal.Width  3.40 (3.20, 3.68)      2.80 (2.53, 3.00)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You just keep adding numbers to the vector in digits to match the numbers you want to style across all of the `continuous2` rows:

```r
library(gtsummary)

tbl_summary(iris, 
            by = Species,
            type = list(Sepal.Length ~ "continuous2"),
            statistic = list(all_continuous2() ~ c("{median} ({p25} - {p75})", 
                                                   "{min} - {max}",
                                                   "{mean} ({sd})")),
            include = c(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width),
            digits = list(all_continuous2() ~ c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))
            ) %>% 
    as.data.frame()

#>   **Characteristic**   **setosa**, N = 50 **versicolor**, N = 50
#> 1       Sepal.Length                 <NA>                   <NA>
#> 2       Median (IQR)   5.0 (4.80 - 5.200)     5.9 (5.60 - 6.300)
#> 3              Range     4.3000 - 5.80000       4.9000 - 7.00000
#> 4          Mean (SD) 5.006000 (0.3524897)   5.936000 (0.5161711)
#> 5        Sepal.Width    3.40 (3.20, 3.68)      2.80 (2.53, 3.00)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>